# Convert GeoTIFF to GeoJSON

Tags: geojson, geotiff-tiff

How can I convert a TIFF file to GeoJSON?
I use QGIS 3.6 on Windows 10.

Comment: Frame challenge: do you actually just want to learn how vectorise a raster dataset, rather than convert specifically between these two formats? This is not an easy transformation, since they are wildly different datatypes.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understand the questions correctly, but it seems that you want to store the geometries and coordinates contained in GeoTIFF in GeoJSON. If you are familiar with Python, ["Rasterio"](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) might help:

> Geographic information systems use GeoTIFF and other formats to
> organize and store gridded raster datasets such as satellite imagery
> and terrain models. Rasterio reads and writes these formats and
> provides a Python API based on Numpy N-dimensional arrays and GeoJSON.